# how to use backpack clone feature for unique field form

Tags: laravel-backpack

Backpack Crud have clone function. But it isn't work when our table has unique field column.
[Backpack clone Documentation](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/3.6/crud-operation-clone)
When table has unique column how to clone it?

```
public function clone($id)
    {
        $this->crud->hasAccessOrFail('clone');
        $this->crud->setOperation('clone');

        $clonedEntry = $this->crud->model->findOrFail($id)->replicate();

        return (string) $clonedEntry->push();
    }
```

Comment: can you provide a sample code that you tried and failed?

Comment: @AhmetOZKESEK I used same thing in Documentation mentioned.
I included code in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recently I experienced the same problem. Here is my solution:

```
public function clone($id)
{
    $this->crud->hasAccessOrFail('clone');
    $this->crud->setOperation('clone');

    $clonedEntry = $this->crud->model->findOrFail($id)->replicate();

    // now resolve the value for unique attribute before save. e.g.
    $slug = Str::slug($clonedEntry->name, '-');
    $count = $this->crud->model->whereRaw("slug RLIKE '^{$slug}(-[0-9]+)?$'")->count();
    $clonedEntry->slug = $count ? "{$slug}-{$count}" : $slug;

    // when you are done, save changes
    return (string) $clonedEntry->push();
}
```

You didn't specify anything about that "unique" attribute. Feel free to customize the resolver according your needs.